# Can't send POST request in android to Grails backend

Tags: android, spring, security, grails

I'm having a little problem sending a POST to my backend, which was made using Grails and SpringSecurity.
I don't know why, but when I send an ROLE_ADMIN method, it's not working. I have tried encoding the user and password and set it on the request header and tried the same but without encoding.
I'm really starting to desperate with this issue.
Here's my POST code:

```
public String POST2(String targetURL, String urlParameters, String user,
            String clave) {
        URL url;
        String h = "http://";
        String u = h+targetURL;

        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        try { // Create connection //
            // targetURL = URLEncoder.encode(targetURL, "UTF-8");
            url = new URL(u);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); // cambiarlo
                                                                    // luego al
                                                                    // usuario q
            String login = user + ":" + clave;
            String encoding = new String(org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64 //
                    .encodeBase64(org.apache.commons.codec.binary.StringUtils //
                            .getBytesUtf8(login)));

            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + login);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "plain/text");// hace
                                                                        // // q
            // sirva // con // el // string // de // json

            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",
                    "" + Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");

            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setReadTimeout(120000); // Send
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(
                    connection.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

            // Get Response 
            InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String line;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
            this.setResponseCode(connection.getResponseCode());
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line);
                response.append('\r');
            }
            rd.close();
            return response.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;

        } finally {

            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is how I call it:

```
private class EntrenadorExecutioner extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        private EntrenadorActivity activity = null;

        public EntrenadorExecutioner(EntrenadorActivity activity) {
            attach(activity);
        }

        private void attach(EntrenadorActivity activity) {
            this.activity = activity;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            activity.startLoader();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String json = "";

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

            try {
                jsonObject.accumulate("cedula", params[0]);
                jsonObject.accumulate("nombre", params[1]);
                jsonObject.accumulate("primerApellido", params[2]);
                jsonObject.accumulate("segundoApellido", params[3]);

                json = jsonObject.toString();
            } catch (JSONException je) {
                je.printStackTrace();
            }

            return rh.POST2(Constantes.GUARDAR_ENTRENADOR, json,
                    Constantes.user.getUsername(),
                    Constantes.user.getPassword());
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
            activity.markAsDone();
            if (response.equals("")) {
                // Refresh the list view then show success
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        getString(R.string.successEntre), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        getString(R.string.err_unexp), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: One thing: when I send a POST request to the login api, it does return user, encoded password and even the token, it's just not working for the rest of services

Comment: Please post some `logcat` out put. What's not working? Is there an exception? Please post more than just your code.

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm kinda new... There's no exception or anything like that, the out put I'm getting is actually the html page that handles login for the web app

Comment: That's something! That should be telling you that your authentication is failing and you're being redirected to the login page, or something to that effect.

Comment: Actually, is not that simple, because in fact is working for the iPhone version of the app, and if I go to a REST client, with the same data, it does log in :/

Comment: Looks like you're using `login` for your basic, instead of `encoding`. You're never using the actual encoded base64 auth for the auth header.

Comment: Actually I tried both, no success. I'm going to try something new, to see what happens. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Try without the content length, content type and just the basic auth and an empty payload - make sure you can actually get past the basic auth. I think that's your problem. The authorization. I encode my basic auth a little different: `byte[] bytes = (username + ":" + password).getBytes(); String basicAuth = new String(Base64.encode(bytes, Base64.NO_WRAP));`

Comment: Found the solution dude, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!
All I needed to do was use the Grails user token, and add it to the headers, like this:

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + Constantes.user.getToken()); // where get token returns the auth token
```